# "Commutativity" of Tor functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

In the book I'm reading now the author says that it's easy to prove the equality $\operatorname{Tor}_i(A, B) = \operatorname{Tor}_i(B, A)$ by doing these manipulations:

(i) Let's consider projective resolutions $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$ of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

(ii) We can show that $\operatorname{Tor}_i(A, B) = H_i(\mathcal P \otimes \mathcal Q)$.

(iii) Now "commutativity" of $\rm Tor$ is an easy corollary of the fact that $\mathcal P \otimes \mathcal Q = \mathcal Q \otimes \mathcal P$.

The proposition (ii) isn't clear for me... Can anyone help me with the understanding of its proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an outline. Let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules and $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be projective resolutions of them respectively. We have quasi-isomorphisms
$$ \mathcal{P} \otimes_R B \leftarrow \mathrm{Tot}(\mathcal{P} \otimes_R \mathcal{Q}) \rightarrow A \otimes_R \mathcal{Q}    $$
which in turn induce isomorphisms 
$$   H_i(\mathcal{P} \otimes_R B) \cong H_i(\mathrm{Tot}(\mathcal{P} \otimes_R \mathcal{Q})) \cong H_i(A \otimes_R \mathcal{Q}).   $$
But then by definition of Tor, we have $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(A, B) \cong H_i(\mathrm{Tot}(\mathcal{P} \otimes_R \mathcal{Q}))$.

Comment: Could you give any hint about the construction of quasi-isomorphism you're using?

Comment: [This set of notes](https://folk.ntnu.no/opperman/HomAlg.pdf) (starting on page 88) has an explanation on how to construct the quasi-isomorphisms for Ext ("balancing Ext"). The process is similar for Tor ("balancing Tor").